# ViewHolder pattern with multiple layouts

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i'm using ViewHolder pattern for fast scroll with no luck heres my code so far:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    ListItem item = getItem(position);

    if(rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if(item.isSectionHeader()) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_header, null);
            viewHolder.header = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.section_header);
        } else {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_coupon, null);
            viewHolder.image = (NetworkImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = ApplicationController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    holder.image.setImageUrl(cell.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.header.setText(cell.getShortDescription());

    return rowView;

}
```

but it crashes the same code without if condition its working any ideas?

```
11-12 13:30:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 13:30:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18745): Process: com, PID: 18745
11-12 13:30:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18745): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 13:30:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18745):    at    ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:128)
11-12 13:30:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18745):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
11-12 13:30:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18745):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
11-12 13:30:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18745):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
11-12 13:30:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(18745):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
```

heres some part of my logcat

Comment: Post your logcat then.....

Answer (score 0):

the `convertView` is only once null. So your `ViewHolder` will be initialized once with `item.isSectionHeader()` or the other case, making one between the TextView and the ImageView always null. Now you have to option:

- `Initialize` both `ImageView` and TextView when the convertView is null, checking for the type afterwards, and hiding the former or the latter depending on the condition
- or, you can override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` to get more the one null `convertView`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = ApplicationController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    holder.image.setImageUrl(cell.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.header.setText(cell.getShortDescription());
```

You don't know for which position is the getView called.
Your imageview will only be initialized if the item is not a section header. So you have to put a check before setting anything on the image view.
If the item is a section header don't use imageView.

Comment: i've try that with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are initializing `viewHolder.header` only if the condition `item.isSectionHeader()` is `true` and `viewHolder.image` only if the condition `item.isSectionHeader()` is `false`.

But while setting the image and setting the text you are not checking the condition.

Just add the condition like below.

```
if(item.isSectionHeader()) {
    holder.header.setText(cell.getShortDescription());
} else {
    holder.image.setImageUrl(cell.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
}
```